# How to write to struct from a GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface, struct, qdial

Using Qt, I'm trying to write to my struct via inputs from a gui.

my target.h file:

```
struct Target{
    double heading;
    double speed;
};
```

my cpp:

```
#include <target.h>

struct Target myship;

myship.heading = 0;
myship.speed = 0;
```

I am using a QDial for the heading as an example.  I can write the value of the QDial to a text file, but I would like to take advantage of structs.

What I'd like to know is how do I access, so that I can write to, the struct in my mainwindow.cpp?

I see that I can access my Target structure in mainwindow.cpp like this:

```
Target.heading
```

But it won't find "myship". I would have thought that I could have done

```
myship.heading...
```

or

```
Target.myship.heading...
```

But neither is working.  When I do Target.heading it gives me the error

```
expected unqualified-id before '.' token
```

My ultimate goal is to have my gui (QDial in this case) write to the struct, and then have my gui (QLabel) display what has been written.  As mentioned before, I have the read/write working with a text file, but I'm currently only writing out a single value, which isn't going to meet my requirements.

I'm new to Qt and structs in general so my guess is I'm missing something pretty trivial, or my understanding is off completely.

Comment: Try to use #include "target.h" instead of #include <target.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `struct` prefix that you've used in the definition of the `myship` variable is a C-ism. It doesn't belong in C++. You should define `myship` as:

```
Target myship;
```

Furthermore, since it's 2016, you should use everything C++11 has got to make your life easier. Initialization of non-static/non-const class/struct members is very helpful and avoids boilerplate at the point of use of the struct. Thus, prefer:

```
// target.h
#include <QtCore>
struct Target {
  double heading = 0.0;
  double speed = 0.0;
};
QDebug operator(QDebug dbg, const Target & target);

// target.cpp
#include "target.h"
QDebug operator(QDebug dbg, const Target & target) {
  return dbg << target.heading << target.speed;
}

// main.cpp
#include "target.h"
#include <QtCore>

int main() {
  Target ship;
  qDebug() << ship;
}
```

Note that you should include your own headers as `#include "header.h"`, not `#include <header.h>`. The latter is reserved for system headers.

[Without Qt](http://ideone.com/06mlyn):

```
#include <iostream>
struct Target {
  double heading = 0.0;
  double speed = 0.0;
};

int main() {
  Target ship;
  std::cout << ship.heading << " " << ship.speed << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kuba. I'm still not understanding how to use this to write to structure.

It still doesn't recognize 'myship' as anything. It still however recognizes 'Target', and provides me with the intelisense provided double parameters.

Shouldn't I be able to simply refer to it directly as 'myship.speed'? 

or am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Comment: @user3229381 `Target.myship` is completely wrong, I don't know where you got that. Forget about it. That's all. Yes `myship.speed` works fine. Try it out.

Comment: The file I'm trying to write to, and then read from is my target.cpp.  I see that I can access myship.speed in main.cpp, but no where else.

mainwindow.cpp is where all of my gui code is, and is where I would have thought that I needed to do the reading and writing of my struct, since that was where, and how I got the reading and writing to work with the text file.

How can I access myship and its parameters from other files?

Comment: @user3229381 Make `myship` a global variable, but put it into a namespace at least.

Comment: Got it thanks.

Still not understanding how to write these values to a file.  I need to take the value from my gui, and store those values in my cpp, or whatever file.  I then will read those values back in and display them on my gui.

I'm using QFile to write to the file, but that isn't letting me write values to those parameters. It just overwrites the whole file with the single value.  How do write the value of parameters so that when i open the file, I see that heading = 23, speed = 56, etc?

Comment: @user3229381 Ok, you just want to store the values in a text file?

Comment: No. I can do that already, but it is overwriting the whole file.  I need to be ableto, or more correctly, I would LIKE to be able to write the values of myship.heading into the file so that if I change it to 12.45, when I close the program, and open it again, the gui will show that the heading is still 12.45. This file needs to contain around 50 parameters so overwriting all 50 parameters with each read and write isn't going to work.  I just need to be able to write to disk the value of the last changed parameter while keeping all of the others intact.

Comment: @user3229381 `QSettings` will do all that for you.

Comment: Thanks Kuba, and will it allow me to read and write as fast the text file?

Comment: @user3229381 It can write to a text file in the `.ini` format, if you really want that. I'd suggest to use the platform-specific default: it will use the registry on Windows, plists on OS X, .ini files on Unix. It's plenty fast.